# Prevent truncated HTTP response from being cached

Tags: httpresponse, browser-cache

We saw this issue on one of our dev machines - the vendor.js bundle in our Angular project had somehow gotten cached, while truncated, which breaks the web app until you clear the cache.

We do use browser caching (together with URL-hashing so caching doesn't prevent app updates).

Is there any way to prevent the browser from caching a truncated request? Actually, I would have thought that the browser has this built-in (i.e. it won't cache a request where the bytes header does not match the amount downloaded).

The browser where we reproduced the problem was Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue - for whatever reason, our HTTP Response was missing the "Content-Length" header in the Response Headers.

The response passes through 2 proxies so one of them might remove the "Content-Length" header.

Answer (score 0):

What we did in such a case is to add a parameter for the request of a lib.

You just need to raise the number and next time the browser and the caches in between will fetch a new version from the server:

e.g. [www.myserver.com/libs/vendor.js?t=12254565](http://www.myserver.com/libs/vendor.js?t=12254565)
[www.myserver.com/libs/vendor.js?t=12254566](http://www.myserver.com/libs/vendor.js?t=12254566)